# Каким образом можно прочитать JSON-файл с использованием JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

У меня есть сайт и json-файл, с такими значениями -`{"latitude":"45,24368","longitude":"38,97343","velocity":"0","distance":"0","date":"10.39.2021_14:39:12","azimuth":"266,5"}`, файл находится на том же сервере, что и сайт. Вроде как слышал, что можно использовать метод parse() и JQuery.getJSON(), но не до конца понимаю, как это сделать.
Вот моя реализация c использованием JQuery:

```
    $.getJSON('token_data.json', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

В этом случае в консоли выходит ошибка - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
Как можно прочитать json с использованием JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким способом

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(addLayerPointTracker, 3000);
});
function addLayerPointTracker() {
    fetch("../token_data.json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

При загрузке страницы происходит запуск функции addLayerPointTracker в которой я использую обращение к тому самому json файлу на сервере, и, с интервалом в 3 секунды ответ выводится в строку.

Comment: так вам и писали, что вы путь неверно указали, здесь же по другому "../token_data.json"

Comment: До того момента, как написал функцию этим способом - пробовал записывать путь по всякому и для примера положил этот файл json в одну дирректорию со скриптом, чтобы понять как работает получение данных - во всех случаях путь к json оказался верным, ошибка была связанна с извлечением данных.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в страницу

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Добавил, ошибка пропала, только данные не выводятся всё равно

Comment: @NickolaiBondarenko Видимо, путь к файлу не тот, который Вы указываете.

Comment: Путь правильный. Дело в том, что если открыть сайт локально то в консоли появится ошибка c путём к тому самому файлу, при открытии которого отобразятся те самые данные, что необходимы - ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/public_html/token_data.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.```

Comment: В чём дело, пока не могу понять

Answer (score 1):

Ваш файл должен быть доступен из сервера. Т.е. ваш контроллер должен вернуть файл на запрос от клиента. Поскольку это простой get [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) запрос на сервер.